# Can't move a file in python? Errno 13- Permission Denied

Tags: python, file, copying

this is my code:

```
def unpack(folders):
for folder in folders:
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    print (files)
    while len(os.listdir(folder)) != 0:
        for file in files:
            if os.path.isdir(file)==False:
                print (file)
                shutil.move(os.path.join(cur_dir,folder,file),os.path.join(cur_dir,file))
            else:
                unpack(file)


    if len(os.listdir(folder))==0:
        os.rmdir(folder)
```

When I call this on the directory this program is in, everything works fine, but I can't copy a file called 'desktop.ini'. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\satvi_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\satvi_000\\Downloads\\others\\desktop.ini' -> 'C:\\Users\\satvi_000\\Downloads\\desktop.ini'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\satvi_000\Downloads\clean_folder.py", line 37, in <module>
    unpack(folders_list)
  File "C:\Users\satvi_000\Downloads\clean_folder.py", line 30, in unpack
    shutil.move(os.path.join(cur_dir,folder,file),os.path.join(cur_dir,file))
  File "C:\Users\satvi_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 558, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\satvi_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\satvi_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\satvi_000\\Downloads\\desktop.ini'
```

I'm guessing this is a system file or something. How do I get past this? It's not completely necessary to move the file, skipping it is fine.

Comment: Wouldn't `try: shutil.move(...) except: pass` be enough? (If it fails, it will ignore the error)

Comment: It looks like the file (where you want to move to) already exists. You could delete that file, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error already contains all information needed: `FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\satvi_000\\Downloads\\others\\desktop.ini' -> 'C:\\Users\\satvi_000\\Downloads\\desktop.ini'`.

A `desktop.ini` file is a hidden system file on Windows, containing Information about special appearances or names of folders.

An example content from a `desktop.ini` file in my `Documents` folder:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-112
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235
```

You can see it contains information about a localized Name (on a German Windows it is automatically displayed as `Dokumente`), a special Icon and sometimes properties of "virutal folders". This means you should **not** try to move around these files, as they could break the proper appearance and properties of folders (think about the recycle bin).

As there are *lots of* `desktop.ini` files on an average windows system, it is not uncommon to run into this kind of problem. On my system, there are currently 166 such files:

```
>>> from glob import glob
>>> print(len(glob(r"c:\**\desktop.ini", recursive=True)))
166
```

Personally I would suggest the same as Nuageux - just `try` to move and log/ignore errors:

```
try:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(cur_dir,folder,file),os.path.join(cur_dir,file))
except FileExistsError as e:
    print("The file {} already exists. Error message: {}".format(os.path.join(cur_dir,file), e))
```

Another way would be to check for every file, if its name is `desktop.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the first error in the stacktrace:

> FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\Users\satvi_000\Downloads\others\desktop.ini' -> 'C:\Users\satvi_000\Downloads\desktop.ini'

The [doc of os.rename (which is used by shutil.move)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) say this about windows:

> On Windows, if dst already exists, OSError will be raised even if it is a file; there may be no way to implement an atomic rename when dst names an existing file

So, you have to check that the file does not exist before moving:

```
if os.path.exists(path):
    continue
```

Comment: Actually I think he gets the OSError because he tries to overwrite a system file and Windows takes offense to that. Running the script that changes it from an elevated command prompt could be an answer?

Comment: @BoboDarph, i don't have a windows on hand to check, but i doubt that a \Downloads\ folder would contain system files.
Also, the error clearly states that it cannot create a file that already exists.
I could be wrong, of course, but i'm pretty sure in this case.

Comment: You can easily find that out if the OP kindly runs the following command: attrib C:\Users\satvi_000\Downloads\others\desktop.ini . If he gets an HS attribute, there's your culprit: https://superuser.com/questions/44812/windows-explorers-file-attribute-column-values